# How to make on update record pass the signal in Django Model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

**Hello I'm trying to make on update trigger in Django Model.**

**Model.py**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    status_type = (
        ('a','Active'),
        ('d','Deactive')
    )
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    gsts = models.ForeignKey(Gst, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sgst = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,null=True,blank=True)
    cgst = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,null=True,blank=True)
    net_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,null=True,blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=status_type, default = 'a')
    create_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    create_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
def ItemGenerator(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        id = instance
        query = Item.objects.get(id = int(id.id))
        #gst calculation
        gst_cal = query.price * query.gsts.gst/100
        #net amount calculation
        net_amounts = query.price + gst_cal        
        #item number generate
        temp_count = Item.objects.all().count()
        no = str('ITEM') + '/' +str(temp_count)
        query = Item.objects.filter(id = id.id).update(code = str(no), cgst = round(gst_cal/2), sgst=round(gst_cal/2), net_amount = round(net_amounts))
```

**When I'm insert to the data post_save signal is call and my price and gst calculation save into data base but problem is that when I'm update the record post_save signal is not working**

Comment: I'm not really following, you say that it is saving in the database, but that updating is not working?

Comment: That being said, I don't really see why it is necessary to calculate these and store these in the database, it looks like data duplication, so this can be moved to properties, not store these as fields.

Comment: When I'm updating existing record at that time post_save() signal is not called.

Comment: For tax calculation  of the  individual  item runtime

Comment: but you check `if created`.

Comment: as for the calculations, these are *not* necessary, you should not store these in the database, you can simply determine these by-need.

Comment: But any solution available or not ??

Comment: remove the `if created`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug, this is expected behavior, your `if created` checks if you run the signal for a *created* object, hence it will not run in case the record is updated.

You can omit this with:

```
def ItemGenerator(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        temp_count = Item.objects.all().count()
        no = str('ITEM') + '/' + str(temp_count)
    else:
        no = instance.code
    gst_cal = instance.price * instance.gsts.gst / 100
    net_amounts = instance.price + gst_cal
    query = Item.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk).update(
        code=no,
        cgst=round(gst_cal / 2),
        sgst=round(gst_cal / 2),
        net_amount=round(net_amounts),
    )
```

But the signal is *not* necessary. Signals are often a pattern to *avoid*. Signals for example *don't* run in case of bulk updates or bulk creates, can easily result in infinite recursion, etc. Here is [an article](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html) I wrote that discusses potential problems with signals.

To make matters worse, this is just *data duplication*, which means that you repeat the same data, but in another shape or form.

```
from django.conf import settings


class Item(models.Model):
    status_type = (('a', 'Active'), ('d', 'Deactive'))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    gsts = models.ForeignKey(Gst, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=status_type, default='a')
    create_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    create_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    @property
    def code(self):
        return f'ITEM/{type(self).objects.filter(create_at__lt=self.create_at).count()}'

    @property
    def cgst_unround(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_cgst'):
            self._cgst = self.price * self.gsts.gsts / 100
        return self._cgst

    @property
    def cgst(self):
        return round(self.cgst_unround, 2)

    @property
    def sgst(self):
        return self.cgst

    @property
    def net_amount(self):
        return round(self.price + self.gst)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This will then determine the values *when needed*, so we can use `some_item.net_amount`, and if so, it will fetch the `.gsts` and do the proper calculations. This will thus also return a different value, if you change the `.price` or for example the `.gst` of the `.gsts`, which is more reliable: if you alter the `gst` of a `Gst` object, signals will not run for the `Item`, although the `net_amount` depends on that change, by just calculating it when needed, that will not be a problem.

In case you need to determine the `.cgst` or `.sgst` for a large amount of objects, it can cause the so-called *N+1* problem. We can omit that by selecting the related `.gsts` of the items before calculating:

```
Item.objects.select_related('gsts')
```

Comment: Where is the link for acticle you forgot to add it i guess :) anyways we have a legacy project that also uses lot of signals that make it slow as signals are synchronous  and i think it is better to move them as background tasks using celery maybe what do you think ?

Comment: @Ahtisham: I've updated with the link. I don't see why a legacy model would be a problem. Given that the fields are always the result of calculations on other fields, these columns can be removed and be determined when needed.

Comment: No they don't do any calculations but create instances of various different models. Some signals connect to a solar on model save to index the search which slows down the save process.